# Combine SQL query for userID with separate query for 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an `SQL query` which filters information by `customerID` in one table and then combine that with information in another table. I have this query which filters by `customerID`

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "
SELECT * 
  FROM booked_activities 
 WHERE customerID LIKE $_SESSION[customerID]

");

               /* INNER JOIN activities ON booked_activities.activityID = activities.activityID);*/
```

The second part I commented out is where I tried to combine the first half of the query with another table.
The `activityID` is a common ID in tables: `booked_activites` and `activities`.

Right now I can output the first query as `activityID` but I need to use the `activityID` to output the `activityName` from the activities table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM booked_activities INNER JOIN activities ON booked_activities.activityID = activities.activityID WHERE booked_activities.customerID LIKE $_SESSION[customerID]`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT *,ac.activityName FROM booked_activities INNER JOIN activities ac ON booked_activities.activityID = activities.activityID 
WHERE customerID LIKE $_SESSION[customerID] );
```

also I would suggest using prepared statement for passing custometr id, instead of using sesstion variable directly in string.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM booked_activities t1
join activities t2 on t2.activityID = t1.activityID
WHERE t1.customerID LIKE $_SESSION[customerID]